# How to make a skewed orthographic perspective camera?

Tags: camera, orthographic

is it possible to have a skewed orthogonal perspective camera?

I want to make a perspective like in the old ultima games where the x and y axis are aligned with the screen and the z axis is at a 45 degree angle.

Essentially the same question has been asked before here: [How can I get a cabinet projection camera?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1888/how-can-i-get-a-cabinet-projection-camera)

However sadly I can't use the proposed solutions there.

I cannot shear the image after rendering because I need the image to be pixel perfect.

Also I cannot transform the rendered model because that will mess with the lighting.

Ideally, I'd like to be able to enter the view transform matrix of the camera directly myself. Can this be done somehow, maybe via scripting?

Comment: Could you bake the lighting in an un-transformed  pass, and then shoot a sheared pass?