# Is it possible to apply modifiers to multiple objects at once?

Tags: modifiers, objects

You can copy modifiers from one object to other objects with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>L</kbd>*> Make links > Modifiers*, or the *Copy attributes* addon.

However, is it possible to *apply* modifiers to many objects at once?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

You can select all of the object you wish to apply the modifiers to, then press <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>C</kbd>*> convert to mesh*:

[image]

Note:

- Some modifiers have different values for *View* and *Render*.
- This will apply the *View* settings.

Comment: This doesn't work if the modifier isn't being displayed in View. Next question... how do you set all modifiers to display in view at once?

Comment: How about for complex modifier stacks? i.e. several array modifiers, curve modifier, lattice modifier, etc. and Multiuser data

Answer (score 16):

### Convert To

One very easy way to do this is to use the Convert To command:

[image]

- If you have curve objects that need to stay curves, then use Convert to Curve
  <kbd>ALT</kbd><kbd>C</kbd> -> Convert to -> Curve from Mesh/Text
- If you have mesh objects that need to stay meshes, then use Convert to Mesh
  <kbd>ALT</kbd><kbd>C</kbd> -> Convert to -> Mesh from Curve/Meta/Surf/Text

This will automatically apply all modifiers at once:

[image]

Answer (score 14):

**Blender 2.8x and 2.9x comes with the add-on "[Modifier Tools](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/addons/interface/modifier_tools.html)".**

The add-on ads four buttons in the top area of the Modifier tab and the entry "Apply All Modifiers" in the menu under "Object" - "Apply".

[image: Menu Entry and Button Locations]

In addition to applying and deleting the entire modifier stack, you can also disable it in the Viewport (Viewport Vis) and collapse/expand all modifiers with the press of one button (Toggle Stack).

Comment: Yes. But this is not working for multiple objects at once.
Additional info: The default shortcut Alt+C isn't working in version up from 2.8.

Comment: @ChristophWerner - It *does* in fact work on multiple objects at once. I just tried it in one of my projects. Select all objects you want to apply modifiers to, then select "Apply All" - done.

Comment: You're are right. It was my fault. I expected it works for the selected object stack only. Thank you!

Comment: @ChristophWerner if you select 2.79 keymaps in BlenderPreferences > Keymap > Presets Alt+C works just fine.