# Applying shrinkwrap modifier corrupts the shape

Tags: modifiers, bezier-curves

I've added lots of circles around a mesh in an effort to retopologize it with `BSurfaces` later. But I never get so far.

I've applied shrinkwrap on them all with the object as the target, and linked the modifier.

This works well so far:

[image]

But then I want to join the objects into one object. This creates problems because it now has only one origin and shrinkwraps all circles towards the new origin:

[image]

So, I thought, to fix this I should apply the modifier to the objects first, so that they retain their shape when they are joined. But if I try to apply the modifier, this happens:

[image]

I have no idea what's going on here.

**Why does it get this shape when I apply the modifier, and how can I fix it?**

And a side-question: How could I apply the modifier to all of the selected rings, instead of one by one?

Comment: See http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/3488/599

Comment: Could you post a .blend?

Comment: @gandalf3 here: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/1706324/test%20retopo.blend

Comment: Just discovered there's duplicate circles on top of each other in that file, so beware...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because the objects are [*Curve*](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Modeling/Curves) objects. Note the warning in the *Info panel* that appears when the modifier is applied:

[image: Applied modifier info]

When the modifier is active (not applied) it affects the polygon geometry generated by the curve object. When you apply the modifier it will only affect the [*Control Vertices*](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Modeling/Curves#Bezier_Curves) (CV points) of the curve, giving a different result:

[image]

As you can see, the CV points are shrink-wrapped to the edges of the mesh, redefining the geometry defined by the curve.

To retain the shape, you must convert the object to a [*Mesh*](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Modeling/Meshes). This can be done with <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>C</kbd>*> Convert > Mesh*. This will take the geometry generated by the curve object and turn it into a mesh object:

[image]

Note that this will apply all modifiers as well. (See [this post](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/3488/599))

Comment: What are "CV points"?

Comment: @DavidS Control Vertices. They are the points that you use to define the shape of the curve.

Comment: So when I apply the modifier, it basically shrinkwraps the control vertices only? In that case, wouldn't they go to the edge of the shrinkwrap target, instead of the weird positions that they do in this case?

Comment: @DavidS. They do go to the edges of the mesh. See my edit

Comment: ahh ok I see now, just didn't look like they did in wireframe view.