# Duplicate Modifier parameters in other objects?

Tags: animation, modifiers, keyframes, geometry

I have multiple objects, all of them are almost the same but scaled or with little modifications, i applied a modifier to one, but i need the same exact parameters to all the other objects, it is possible to duplicate those parameters on the other objects?

Thanks in regard.

Comment: First select (in Object Mode) all the objects you want to have a modifier and then the object with a modifier enabled. Press CTRL+L (Make Links)-->Modifiers. See these answers: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/319/add-the-same-modifier-to-multiple-objects-at-once , http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/3488/is-it-possible-to-apply-modifiers-to-multiple-objects-at-once

Comment: Are you asking how to copy the exact same modifier to other objects or how to apply modifiers to multiple objects?

Comment: I wanto to copy the exact modifier parameters to other objects, also those modifier parameters also have keyframes already made.

Comment: @Gonzou It worked!!! :D