# Problem exporting model from Blender to 3DS Max

Tags: texturing, materials, objects, export

I'm having some trouble exporting a model with textures to be imported into 3DS Max. I decided to use the OBJ exporter. For some reason the model is all screwed up when I import it into 3DS Max.

How it looks in Blender:
[image: model in blender]

How it looks in 3DS Max:
[image: exported obj in 3DS Max]

Comment: Did you apply your modifiers in Blender before exporting?

Comment: Nice character model you've got there :D

Comment: Um, I am extremely new to Blender. How do I apply my modifiers in Blender....?

Comment: [Alt-C will apply all modifiers](http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/3489/935) or you can apply individual ones in the modifiers properties, undo after exporting to get them back, the obj exporter also has an option to apply modifiers when exporting. Are the normals all facing out? In edit mode select all and Ctr-N

Comment: Thanks for the help guys, I really appreciate it. So I am pretty sure that I made all the normals facing out. I had to select each individual object (because the model is split up into: 1. legs, torso, arms, head 2. dogtag necklace 3. hat 4. headphones 5. socks and shoes) go into Edit Mode, do 'A' to select all, then I did CTRL+N, for all 5 objects. And "Apply Modifiers" was checked when I exported the OBJ. Same exact result in 3DS Max when I imported it. Gosh, I am sure there is just some simple thing that I am doing wrong. If there was some way I could send the blender file to you guys....

Comment: @Jacob, what you do to send a blender file is to find a host (I use Dropbox), and upload the file there, then post a link to the file in your question. Others mentioned applying any modifiers already. But did you apply location? This is done by selecting (in object mode in Blender) either all of the sub objects, or each of them in turn, and pressing <kbd>CTRL-Akey</kbd>. This resets the location (or if you changed them, but I don't see evidence that you did), the scale and rotation of you model. The issues with the hat, and perhaps the face look to me to be issues with the normals.

Comment: Thanks a ton @brasshat ! https://mega.co.nz/#!jsM3jZqD!IgejnGGIs4nqdu2h6qSei1b-ZgQeeTCePGKqDnCC2SM

Comment: related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/24481/how-to-properly-export-scene-to-3ds-max/24527#24527

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. I solved the problem by changing the export settings

[image]

Comment: Just a thought, you might try FBX, its a much more modern, not so buggy file system, which also supports a lot more than what obj does.