# Is there a way to add a specific modifier to more than one object?

Tags: workflow, modifiers, objects

I know you can [copy the modifiers after adding it to one object](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/319/599), but is it possible to add one specific modifier to many objects at once?

For instance, I have many objects with different modifiers and I want to make them all collision objects. If I use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>L</kbd> it copies all the modifiers on the active object to the selected objects. I only want to add a collision modifier to the existing modifiers.

Is this possible?

Comment: The first idea I can think is make a simple object with the modifier alone, and copy from there( but can make duplicates if you already copy it) I can only think on made a custom script for do this. Not looks complicated, in any way.

Comment: @gabrign That won't work because copying overwrites all the existing modifiers on the selected objects.. Looks like your are right, this needs a script :/

Comment: See http://adaptivesamples.com/2016/01/06/cif-18-alt-click/

Comment: @iKlsR I wish.. But doesn't seem to work for adding modifiers (only modifying them)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As I experiened, the **Copy Attributes Menu** addon can well support this. You can find *Copy Seleced Modifers* down the menu, which will only copy sepcific modifier(s) without replacing the original stack. Hope it helps.

[image]

Comment: This is the best solution. Simply enable the add-on in the Blender preferences, select the source and one or more target objects at the same time with the active element being the one to copy one or more modifiers to other objects. Then press `Ctrl`+`C` and select "Copy Selected Modifiers", toggle one or more modifiers and press "OK". With properly named modifiers in the source object, this makes it very easy to select only the modifiers that you really want to copy.