# How to copy Modifiers

Tags: materials, modifiers, interface

I must be doing something wrong, I select my object which has two modifiers, press space, search for "Copy Modifier", and select it. I get the error message

"**The object the data pointer refers to is not a valid modifier**"

I have also had no luck with copying stuff like Materials.

Answer (score 7):

Searching the error message in the source code shows 3 occurances, it appears that the "*Copy Modifiers*" operator is only available for some freestyle settings.

```
blender-2.69\source\blender\editors\render\render_shading.c
            BKE_report(op->reports, RPT_ERROR, "The object the data pointer refers to is not a valid modifier");
            BKE_report(op->reports, RPT_ERROR, "The object the data pointer refers to is not a valid modifier");
            BKE_report(op->reports, RPT_ERROR, "The object the data pointer refers to is not a valid modifier");
```

As described here [Add the Same Modifier to Multiple Objects at Once?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/319/add-the-same-modifier-to-multiple-objects-at-once) you could link the modifiers using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>L</kbd> (Make Links) and select *Modifiers*.

Python:

```
bpy.ops.object.make_links_data(type='MODIFIERS')
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way I've found to copy all the modifiers for an object is to tab out to Object mode and duplicate the object. Then tab into edit, select all, and delete. Then add your mesh while inside edit mode. This will apply all the modifiers to the new object. Works for me, i just wish there was a shortcut.

Comment: Why not use Ctrl+L > Modifiers?

Answer (score -2):

You need to run these copy operators in a proper context, or they won't know what to copy.

- In *Properties Editor*, use the *Copy* button in the *Modifiers* tab to duplicate.
- In *Material* tab, use the *Material Specials* menu button (red arrow) and chose *Copy Material*.
  *Paste Material* with *Material.001* selected would copy the material settings over and make it purple as well. It does not create a new material or replace the slot by *Material*.

  [image: Modifier / Material Copy]

Comment: The copy button in the modifiers tab does duplicate the modifier for the current object can it also be pasted to another object?

Comment: No it can´t, it just duplicate the Modifier to the stack of the same object. Theres gotta be a way to Copy/Paste in 3D viewport Modifiers & Materials. That´s the context you would optimally perform such operations.