# Applying array modifier to multiple items

Tags: modifiers

I want to create a "wheel of fortune" type wheel.

[image: Wheel of Fortune wheel]

To do this I created a single segment that could be shown multiple times. It consists of a slice, some edge poles and a text.

[image]

I then planned on duplicating this using the array modifier. In order to apply an array modifier to all of these things (to have multiple instances), I parented them to an empty.

I then thought I could apply the array modifier to the empty. But this does not seem to be possible. What am I thinking wrong?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Add the Same Modifier to Multiple Objects at Once?](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/319/add-the-same-modifier-to-multiple-objects-at-once)

Comment: The OP was talking specifically about a kind of "group array" function, I don't think that's strictly a duplicate.

Comment: I don't think it is likely to happen now, you have to either adding array for each object, or join them as a single object. But you can use other method like [Dupliverts](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Modeling/Objects/Duplication/DupliVerts) to achieve the same goal.

Comment: Is there some way to group these objects and then apply the array to that group?

Answer (score 3):

Use the following settings for the Array modifier and be sure to add the empty for the Object Offset.  Note that the Modifier should be added to the object that is being duplicated and not the Empty.

[image]

Now rotate the Empty

[image]

Comment: That's good, +1. But it doesn't show how to add the modifier to several objects, and that's what I interpreted the question to be about. @Bemmu If this answer is what you wanted, let me know, so I can retract my closevote.

Comment: SixthOfFour as you said this was not what I was looking for (although it certainly is a necessary part of the solution, but one which I already knew about).

Answer (score 1):

What you might do is joining your objects first and then aply the trick as described by MarcClintDion.

Note that if you made several segments with some text, it might be more easy
to create one "backgroundblade" change its origin to center of the wheel. (set origin to cursor (hit space type origin) and place cursor at center.

Duplicate object view times, for all your texts
join each different text to each blade.

now for each blade, using snap perform Object to Cursor (center of wheel)
And type in object mode RZ30  or RZ25 something like that Repeat till proper position.

(its just another way of doing this)

Comment: Thanks. It's been so long I can barely remember why I needed to do this back then, but I appreciate your answer.