# How to modify accurate 3D models to protect technical know-how

Tags: mesh, modifiers, export, workflow

I have a 3D model from our engineering department with accurate measures of our product (format: VRML) that I want to give to a third party. The third party doesn't need an accurate model for what they are supposed to do with it. Now I want to modify the whole model with little effort to protect our technical know-how.

Does anybody know a solution in Blender to accomplish that?

I played a little bit with the decimate modifier and it looked promising.
The draw back I see with it, is the disproportionate effort I have to make since I don't know how to apply the modifier on ALL faces of ALL objects in the model.

Is it possible to get a short step-by-step tutorial to get all faces modified at once?

Another question that comes to my mind regarding the protection effect: If I modify the model and export it again to the VRML-format, then the modification I made in Blender is definite/destructive in opposite to the Blender-format itself where it stays non-destructive and I can adjust the modifier again. Am I right?

Comment: you can setup your decimate on 1 object, select everything with A, be sure your modified mesh is active and Ctrl+L to link the modifiers from it. I think modifiers are applied when exporting, so it'll be destructive. can be a checkbox (depending on file format)

Comment: @Bithur that looks like it may be the answer. Would you mind saying the same thing in an answer maybe with a few screen shots? Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Setup your decimate modifier on one of the objects.

Then, in object mode, select all objects (<kbd>A</kbd>) or all needed object (<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>RMB</kbd>).

Make sure your decimated object is active (different color, usually brighter orange), if it's not, <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>RMB</kbd> on it.

Use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> to open the link menu and select "modifiers"
[image]

All the selected objects will now have the exact same modifiers as the active object.
[image]

About export : modifiers are applied when exporting, so it will be destructive. There can be a checkbox (depending on file format) to apply modifiers or not.

Comment: Sorry but I had a lot of work and couldn't post a full answer with screenshots before.

Comment: Thanks for the input. I tried this, but I couldn't get all objects with "A", it only selected all faces of the selected object. However, I got all objects selected with the lasso tool and used the copy-attributes-addon described here: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/319/add-the-same-modifier-to-multiple-objects-at-once

Comment: you tried to select objects in edit mode, go in object mode (Tab)