# How to copy and paste a single modifier?

Tags: modifiers, interface, workflow, shortcut

I have multiple objects with different sets of modifiers, but I want all of them to have the exact same *Array Modifier*.

Unfortunately the only way I've found to copy and paste modifiers is to select everything and do <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd> to copy the entire stack of modifiers, not an individual modifier.

Is there any way to copy and paste a single modifier without having to manually re-add it to every object?

Comment: Possible duplicate - http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/1079/1245 ? The only difference is that you should select the object with desired modifier *last*

Comment: @MrZak Does that add-on add modifiers from the active object to the selected objects, or does it entirely replace them (similar to Ctrl + L)?

Comment: It *copies* modifiers from the *active* object to another *selected* one (where comes its name from - Copy attirbutes menu). You should be able to find it as in 2.75 it's added, but not enabled

Comment: I'll give it a try and see if works.

Comment: Related: https://agenzasbrothers.com/en/blender-tip-30-changing-modifier-settings-on-multiple-objects-at-once/

Comment: At least for VSE [Strip Modifiers](https://developer.blender.org/rBcd71d9e) this is now possible since 2.77.