# How to unset multiple values from Bezier objects?

Tags: workflow, bezier-curves

I'm creating poly hair using Bezier Curves. I set the bevel Object to create a solid object but right now I want to unset that value from multiple objects curves. Why? because some curves really looks strange so I have to fix this manually

I mean how to set and unset this from multiple bezier object curves, it's really a lot of work clicking multiple times for do this repeating work.

I also check this.
[Add the Same Modifier to Multiple Objects at Once?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/319/add-the-same-modifier-to-multiple-objects-at-once)
It doesn't work on Curves.

[image: The Problem]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is.
Set it for the active object, then right-click the property and select the option *Copy to Selected*

[image]