# How can i Mirror more than one objects at the same time?

Tags: objects, mirror, groups

I want to mirror a lot of objects at the same time. How can i do that? I am tryed group objects but i don't know how i can mirror group. I am sharing a photo about this problem: [image]

Comment: If you don't want joining objects into one then add Mirror modifier to one object and then link it to others, see https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/319/add-the-same-modifier-to-multiple-objects-at-once

Comment: Thank you very much. that is a right answer. :))
https://image.prntscr.com/image/0KRaCWjbTKqgyTOexF2W3g.png

Comment: @MrZak If Emulate 3 button mouse is on (tick mark) it doesnt work. How then? it is possible

Comment: @atek your comment isn't clear. What doesn't work? Linking modifiers should be and is possible with Emulate 3 button mouse or without (as of 2.79). If you face unexpected behaviour ask a question. Finally I barely see a reason to use addon for that

Comment: @MrZak with the comment given with the alt key above. I have enable the 3 button mouse option and when i try to press alt key and press on wire frame ,etc its not working. And below the answer the addon can work with any modifier without joining.

Comment: @atek as above - if you have a question, ask a quesiton. You seem to be asking another question rather than one asked by OP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Download Smart Join [Addon](https://bitbucket.org/aivanis/smart-join/downloads/)

Select the mesh (wheel) and click on smart join (it temporary join all the selected mesh). You can now move all the join mesh and add any modifier to all the join mesh. 
If you want to separate the mesh just click the separate s. join

If you want to edit the join mesh click on the expand smart join and after finishing the editing click on collapse smart join.

[image]

Comment: yes you are doing well but where did you open smart join?

Comment: @özcanözaltın 3D view Toolshelf (Press T -> Relationship)