Can I convert "Linked Duplicate" objects to "Instance Collection"?
I used the Linked Duplicate workflow to layout a scene where each object's mesh all share the same one (see below). Now I need the ability to add modifiers and create hierarchical objects instead of a single bespoke mesh, and seems I need Collection Instance workflow. I saw this post which doesn't quite fit my problem.
How can I convert my current scene to replace the current objects with Collection Instances?


I'm not sure why you would need Collection instances (instances are basically linked objects) but you could convert your objects to Single User, by going inside the object menu (in object mode) > Relations > Make single user.

I think I need Collection Instance because modifiers are only applied on an object by object basis, also if the object is hierarchical it won't be replicated either if only mesh data is linked.

"Hierarchical objects" doesn't make sense in the context of Blender. You can absolutely add modifiers to linked duplicates however. What are you trying to do ?

I'm trying to add bevel modifier to a linked duplicate, and also add a child object. Currently if I modify the linked mesh it updates everywhere which is great but if I add a modifier it only effects whichever duplicated object I put it on. Also, if I parent another mesh to the duplicated object it doesn't appear on the others either. So the problem I'm trying to solve is I want instances of a hierarchy of objects with modifiers attached. If I modify any instance, all other instances are updated too.

Here is another post with similar issue. It can be done but you have to keep applying it to each individual object. Hence I think I need Collection Instance? https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/175335/how-do-i-add-the-same-modifiers-to-all-linked-duplicates
