# Modifier Settings do not Copy Using Link or Copy Attributes

Tags: modifiers, linked-data

1. Default blend file
2. duplicate default cube
3. add cloth modifier to one.
4. change a setting within the modifier - for example vertex weight
5. Control - L - Link objects and choose modifier

- or:

6. Enable copy attributes add-on and use control - C copy selected modifiers.

Result: neither methods will copy the modifiers WITH their settings - for example cache bake range.

Does anyone know of a way of duplicating modifiers WITH their settings to multiple objects?

Here is thread discussing copying modifiers but I need to copy the settings as well. Any thoughts anyone?

[Add the Same Modifier to Multiple Objects at Once?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/319/add-the-same-modifier-to-multiple-objects-at-once)

Comment: and where exactly is vertex weight in cloth modifier? ;) ...aaahh..you need vertex mass, right?

Comment: Yep. I just used that as an example. Change any of the settings and see if you can get them to copy to other objects whether instanced or not. I am making a kelp forrest with a submarine smashing through it...I have at least 20 kelp plants involved in the cloth simulation and I had to manually change the settings. You can save your own preset, but you have to set the cache range individually. OR - there is something I am missing.

Comment: I am not totally sure, but I think the physics settings are not really part of the modifier. That‘s why they will not be copied. And that’s why you do not change the settings in the modifiers tab.

Comment: Ok so how would one copy the modifiers physics settings? You can make a preset that will copy most settings, but not, say, the cache range. I can't believe there isn't a way...someone must have come across this situation before....